# Removing all characters and numbers except last variable with dash symbol

Tags: php, preg-replace

Hi I want to remove a characters using preg_replace in php so i have this code here which i want to remove the whole characters, letters and numbers except the last digit(s) which has dash(-) symbol followed by a digits so here's my code.

`echo preg_replace('/(.+)(?=-[0-9])|(.+)/','','asdf1245-10');`

I expect the result will be

`-10`

the problem is above is not working very well. I checked the pattern using http://www.regextester.com/ it seems like it works, but on the other side http://www.phpliveregex.com/ doesn't work at all. I don't know why but anyone who can help to to figure it out?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

```
echo preg_replace('/^.+?(-[0-9]+)?$/','$1','asdf1245-10');
```

**Output:**

```
-10
```

and

```
echo preg_replace('/^.+?(-[0-9]+)?$/','$1','asdf124510');
```

**Output:**

```
<nothing>
```

Comment: @user1256346: `$1` stands for the content of group 1, this is what is inside the first pair of parenthesis.

Comment: @toto I would upvote your answer but I find it more like a statement :-x

Answer (score 0):

My first thinking is to use **explode** in this case.. make it simple like the following code.

```
$string = 'asdf1245-10';
$array = explode('-', $string);
end($array);
$key = key($array);
$result = '-' . $array[$key];
```

$result => '-10';

Answer (score 0):

An other way:

```
$result = preg_match('~\A.*\K-\d+\z~', $str, $m) ? $m[0] : '';
```

pattern details:

```
\A     # start of the string anchor
.*     # zero or more characters
\K     # discard all on the left from match result
-\d+   # the dash and the digits
\z     # end of the string anchor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace('/(\w+)(-\w+)/','$2', 'asdf1245-10');
```